# how to setup connection between html app and azure or firebase in visual studio 2013...?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, azure, firebase

I am developing javascript app using HTML in visual studio 2013. I want to use Microsoft Azure or Firebase for database but visual studio showing the error..

This is the code provided by azure to connect database.

```html
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient( "https://onlinepolicestation.azure-mobile.net/", "awTfASDTrumVMrQsqEFfgzVSSaFJFd27" );
```

I run the app, getting the same error in azure and firebase database connectivity.

This is the error showing by visual studio
and the same error was getting when i use script code for Firebase.

**0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'WindowsAzure' is undefined**

Comment: I've never used Windows Azure myself, but from the error message it looks like you forgot to include `MobileServices.Web-<version>.js`. See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#create-client

Comment: i had already included the 
'<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js"></script>'
but its not working the error was same. 
**WindowsAzure is undefined**
@FrankvanPuffelen